# добавление обновление удаление в источнике

Tags: c#, winforms, ado.net

```
//Program.cs

using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Updates
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();

            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }


    }
}
```

```
//CustomersUpdate.cs
//В этом блоке описаны основные ф-ии. InsertCustomers, ChangeCustomers, DeleteCustomers (изменяющие источник) при этом для DeleteCustomers не требуется форма, тк и сохранят в таблицу приложения ничего не надо.  
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Updates.Commands
{
    static class CustomersUpdates
    {
        public static void InsertCustomers(DataRow customersRow)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=WIN-9VNS32J8479\IVAN;Initial Catalog=ShopDB;Integrated Security=True";
            string commandString = "INSERT Customers " +
                                   "VALUES (@FName, @LName, @MName, @Address1, @Address2, @City, @Phone, @DateInSystem) SELECT CustomerNo FROM Customers WHERE CustomerNo = @@IDENTITY";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FName", customersRow[1]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LName", customersRow[2]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MName", customersRow[3]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address1", customersRow[4]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address2", customersRow[5]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("City", customersRow[6]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Phone", customersRow[7]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateInSystem", customersRow[8]);

                try
                {
                    customersRow.Table.Columns[0].ReadOnly = false;
                    customersRow.SetField<int>(0, (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()); //как я понимаю cmd возвращает новую введеную в источник строку и каким по образом преобразует ее в int?
                    //а затем записывается в 0-ю ячейку строки customersRow?? Непонятно что делает cmd.ExecuteScalar()?
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    customersRow.Table.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
                }

                customersRow.AcceptChanges();
            }
        }

        public static void ChangeCustomers(DataRow customersRow)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=WIN-9VNS32J8479\IVAN;Initial Catalog=ShopDB;Integrated Security=True";

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            string commandString = "UPDATE Customers " +
                                   "SET FName = @FName," +
                                   "LName = @LName," +
                                   "MName= @Mname," +
                                   "Address1 = @Address1," +
                                   "Address2 = @Address2," +
                                   "City = @City," +
                                   "Phone = @Phone," +
                                   "DateInSystem = @DateInSystem " +
                                   "WHERE CustomerNo = @CustomerNo";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustomerNo", customersRow[0]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("FName", customersRow[1]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("LName", customersRow[2]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("MName", customersRow[3]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address1", customersRow[4]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Address2", customersRow[5]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("City", customersRow[6]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Phone", customersRow[7]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DateInSystem", customersRow[8]);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            customersRow.AcceptChanges();
        }

        public static void DeleteCustomers(DataRow customersRow)
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=WIN-9VNS32J8479\IVAN;Initial Catalog=ShopDB;Integrated Security=True";

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            string commandString = "DELETE Customers " +
                                   "WHERE CustomerNo = @CustomerNo";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandString, connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustomerNo", customersRow[0, DataRowVersion.Original]);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        public static void Update(DataTable customers)
        {
            foreach (DataRow customer in customers.Rows)
            {
                if (customer.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted)
                    DeleteCustomers(customer);
                if (customer.RowState == DataRowState.Added)
                    InsertCustomers(customer);
                if (customer.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
                    ChangeCustomers(customer);
            }
            customers.AcceptChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

```
//Main Form.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Updates.Commands;

namespace Updates
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=WIN-9VNS32J8479\IVAN;Initial Catalog=ShopDB;Integrated Security=True";
        string commandString = "SELECT * FROM Customers";

        DataTable customers = new DataTable("Customers");

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(commandString, connectionString);
            adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
            adapter.Fill(customers);

            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = customers; //первая форма отображается в GridView
        }

        private void addButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //?? как понимаю обработчик для кнопки Add (ввод новой записи)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult result = new AddCustomerDialog(customers).ShowDialog();
        }

        private void modifyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //это видимо обработчик кнопки Update (обновление выбранной записи)
        {
            var editDialog = new EditCustomerDialog(customers, (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row); //возвращаем в переменную editDialog объект типа EditCustomerDialog

            editDialog.ShowDialog();

        }

        private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //обработчик Ok Cancel
        {
            DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show("Вы уверены что хотите удалить этого клиента?", "DeleteDialog", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);

            if (res == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                var rowToDelete = (dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
                rowToDelete.Delete();

                CustomersUpdates.DeleteCustomers(rowToDelete);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

```
//Addcustomerdialog
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Updates.Commands;


namespace Updates
{
    public partial class AddCustomerDialog : Form
    {

        DataTable table;

        public AddCustomerDialog(DataTable table)
        {
            this.table = table;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void AddCustomerDialog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CenterToScreen();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // подтверждение ок button для insert
        {
            DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
            newRow["FName"] = textBox1.Text.Count() == 0 ? null : textBox1.Text; //как я понимаю считаем есть ли символы в текстбоксе. Если нет оставляем null, иначе берем содержимое текстбокса.
            newRow["LName"] = textBox2.Text.Count() == 0 ? null : textBox2.Text;
            newRow["Address1"] = textBox3.Text.Count() == 0 ? null : textBox3.Text;
            newRow["City"] = textBox4.Text.Count() == 0 ? null : textBox4.Text;
            newRow["Phone"] = textBox5.Text.Count() == 0 ? null : textBox5.Text;

            try
            {
                table.Rows.Add(newRow);

                DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;

                CustomersUpdates.InsertCustomers(newRow);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Close();
            }

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // cancel button for insert in Customers 
        {
            DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

```
//EditCustomersDialog.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Updates.Commands;


namespace Updates
{
    public partial class EditCustomerDialog : Form
    {
        DataTable table; //во втором проекте этой строки не было
        DataRow rowToEdit;

        public EditCustomerDialog(DataTable table,  DataRow rowToEdit) //это конструктор EditCustomerDialog //таблицу во втором проекте не подавали
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
            this.rowToEdit = rowToEdit;
            this.table = table; //эта строка была закомитена во 2-м проекте

            CenterToScreen();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                rowToEdit["FName"] = textBox1.Text; //здесь мы изменяем конкретные ячейки строки. значения берем из текстбоксов которые заполняет клиент в воторой форме(после нажатия Update)
                rowToEdit["Address1"] = textBox3.Text;
                rowToEdit["City"] = textBox4.Text;
                rowToEdit["Phone"] = textBox5.Text;

                CustomersUpdates.ChangeCustomers(rowToEdit); //??во втором update проекте  было rowToEdit.Тable 
                //то есть мы передавали всегда Table, где происходила проверка на Modify, каждой строки, а здесь получается передаем одну строку, а как же другие строки?

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            this.Close();

        }

        private void EditCustomerDialog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            textBox1.Text = rowToEdit["FName"].ToString(); //текстбоксам присваиваются значения которые пользователь подтвердил нажав ок после воода во второй форме (стороки кода№30-48) 
            textBox2.Text = rowToEdit["LName"].ToString();
            textBox3.Text = rowToEdit["Address1"].ToString();
            textBox4.Text = rowToEdit["City"].ToString();
            textBox5.Text = rowToEdit["Phone"].ToString();
        }


        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример начала выполнения (первая форма) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ответьте, пожалуйста, на вопросы

1)(Форма EditCustomerDialog.cs) В строке CustomersUpdates.ChangeCustomers(rowToEdit); //во втором Update проекте  было rowToEdit.Тable
то есть мы передавали всегда Table, где происходила проверка на Modify, каждой строки, а здесь получается передаем одну строку, а как же другие строки?

2)(Файл CustomerUpdate.cs)                 try

```
                customersRow.SetField<int>(0, (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()); //как я понимаю cmd возвращает новую введеную в источник строку и каким по образом преобразует ее в int?!
```

А затем записывается в customersRow.
2.1) Непонятно что делает cmd.ExecuteScalar()?
2.2) Также читал сдесь https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.setfield?view=netframework-4.8
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но в коде передается только два значения, а не три. Не ясно 0 это номер столбца или строки?

```
            }
```

2. 

Comment: Не понятно зачем вы постоянно создаёте вопросы, такого рода? В чем смысл? Зачем? Если вы изучаете то почему вопрос адресуется сюда а не к источнику ваших знаний?

Comment: **Для закрывающих:** Данный человек постоянно создает новую учетную запись, не понимая, что нарушает тем самым правила ресурса. У него есть несколько учетных записей, с одной из он [признался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1156101) в том, что делает это в целях обойти лимит. Сами вопросы от него вида "что эта строчка кода делает?", что не имеет ценности для базы SO. Достаточно посмотреть на метку [ado.net] и увидеть там свыше 20 вопросов, заданных с разных аккаунтов. Предлагаю расценивать его как спамера!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Форма EditCustomerDialog.cs) В строке CustomersUpdates.ChangeCustomers(rowToEdit); //во втором Update проекте было rowToEdit.Тable то есть мы передавали всегда Table, где происходила проверка на Modify, каждой строки, а здесь получается передаем одну строку, а как же другие строки? - Другие строки успешно, перебираются и в зависимости `customer.RowState` удаляются, обновляются либо добавляются.
2. Непонятно что делает cmd.ExecuteScalar() - (Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query.) - выполняет запрос и возвращает значение первую колонку первой записи в результата возвращаемого запросом.

Comment: 1)Правильно понимаю в случае мы передаем строку и 1.1)св-во Table автоматически вызывается при передаче? или 1.2)св-во Table не вызывается на строке, но перебор все равно происходит за счет связи cтроки и таблицы в GridView?

Comment: 2)Правильно понимаю cmd должно вставлять данные в источник. Но мы перед этим (2.1)или после?) 2.2)вставляем одну ячейку выбранной пользователем строки в  customersRow?

Comment: Не понятно какой смысл в ваших ответах? Раз человек не понимает, что нарушает правила ресурса, обходя вечно ограничение на вопросы, раз человек сам не хочет учить базовые вещи и понимать что и как, так какой смысл отвечать ему? Репутация? Ну вот удалят его, вопрос закроют, снимут с вас репу. Помочь ему? А смысл? Если через пару часов появится похожий вопрос, где будет видно, что ему ваши слова были по боку.

Comment: Смысл, думаете есть он в удалении или закрывании? Ему не отвечаешь он все равно спамит.

Comment: Это на сегодня по моему 2 вопрос. Я на один не ответил ток он второй накатал

Comment: На счет репы, а смыл её. Думаете с репой овер 100к не делают ошибок? лично мне это запас для задания вопросов которые меня интересуют и что не банили его. А от этого лично мне опыт в объяснении. Как говорится испытание терпения

Comment: Киньте тревогу как спамер и идите дальше со спокойной душой, рано или поздно этого троля забанит система полностью, но давать ему то, что он хочет, ну как то бредово.

Comment: ok кидал уже несколько раз. он вылезает и вылезает. Я то решил может закончить с его вопросами ответив на них. Я уже сказал ему позвонить чтоб за 5 минут объяснить все

Comment: Уже 30 (а то и больше) вопросов от человека, где он говорит "я раскручиваю метку ado.net" и все они бестолковые... Ну удачи, я не думаю что он вообще пытается разобраться, просто тролит нас да и все, ну либо школьник, которого оставили на лето учиться и он выносит мозг теперь окружающим. Вы поймите, он писал с одной учетной записи, вопросы были низкого качества, ему система кинуло блок, чтоб он обдумал свои вопросы, но нет, он вместо того, что бы улучшить качество вопросов сделал новую учетку, получил блок, сделал еще одну, получил и там блок и так много раз. Думаете объяснение что либо даст?

Comment: Хм всё спасибо, буду иметь ввиду.